# Can interrupting mounting and dismounting cause data loss?

Tags: encryption, mount, storage, disk-encryption

I'm using veracrypt to safely store files. Occasionally it seems to hang (for 5-10 minutes or more) when mounting a volume. So I gravitate towards force quitting the application, ejecting the volume, and starting over.

Can force quitting during mounting or unmounting cause any data loss, or will this type of operation never allow data to be corrupted?

Please presume that the volume (external hard drive) would never be in the process of copying a file to or from, but that the force quit only occurs at a time when no files are being moved (e.g. during mounting or unmounting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have seen, the result is a matter of luck and it can go both ways.

The result of interrupting the mount will in most cases be the same as interrupting
the booting of Windows, meaning without a problem.

However, if veracrypt or Windows were writing to the headers of the encrypted volume,
the data may be lost. I would assume that the veracrypt developers tried to take care
of such a possibility, but I have found evidence that it can happen.

In the post
[Corrupt Veracrypt file help!](https://www.reddit.com/r/VeraCrypt/comments/acajpr/corrupt_veracrypt_file_help/)
the poster writes this sad story:

> I have a Veracrypt container of important documents. Tonight I was going to open it up to put on my server and create a backup. I went to mount it on my machine and my computer just crashed. I rebooted it. Now when I come to remount the veracrypt container I get the error "Cannot mount as the file is in use." (or something along those lines, I don't want to mess with it too much as I'm worried I'll cause more damage.)

My advice is then to wait for veracrypt to complete the mount.
Interrupting it may only cause harm in one case out of a thousand,
but don't risk it unless you have good backups, just in case.

Comment: Great research. I had naively assumed software would be written in a way so to as avoid this, but I'm very glad I asked (better safe than sorry!)